# How to get NeHotspotHelper Entitlements

Tags: ios, swift, wifi, nehotspothelper

I have submitted this form like they said https://developer.apple.com/contact/network-extension/

and then I got email from apple

> Please note that as of November 10, 2016 this process is not required
>   for developers who wish to use App Proxy, Content Filter, or Packet
>   Tunnel AP

and then I have enabled network extensions in

https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle

but when I add com.apple.developer.networking.hotspothelper in entitlements and compile my Xcode  I got this error message

> The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.
>   The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file are invalid, not permitted, or do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016).

Answer (score 0):

Below is the complete text, Which i have received.

> Thank you for requesting information about the Network Extension framework. Please note that as of November 10, 2016 this process is not required for developers who wish to use App Proxy, Content Filter, or Packet Tunnel APIs. To use these services please navigate to your Developer Account at https://developer.apple.com/account/ and select the Network Extension capability for the App ID you will be using for your app.
>
> If you are requesting an entitlement for Hotspot Helper APIs your request will be addressed at our earliest convenience.

Second paragraph stated to wait till they are processing it.

Wait for 3 weeks to 3 month. They will process it and approve/reject it according to your request and application behaviour. If you have any additional info or need some explanation revert them in approval/rejection mail instead of requesting again. I got it in list 2 weeks ago, was submitted in Oct-nov 2019.